# Get Craft working on HHVM?

Tags: installation

Has anyone successfully run craft on an HHVM server?  I tried it using [Forge](http://forge.laravel.com), I got a page loading, but no admin and no subpages.

According to the [HHVM Frameworks page](http://hhvm.com/frameworks/), it has 99.7 percent compatibility with yii and 100% compatible with twig? I guess that last 0.3% is a doozy.

I'd love to hear if anyone else had had more success with it?

Comment: It's either that last 0.3% of Yii or something additional that Craft is doing that's not compatible with HVVM.  It's on my list to test Craft's HVVM compatibility, though.

Comment: Where is the newset link on this topic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t recommend it until Yii is 100% compatible. And I’m guessing there’s not a lot of motivation to do that, since Yii 2 is almost out and is pretty much a complete rewrite.

Comment: Makes sense.  And ironically enough it looks like the yii2 team just started officially testing against hhvm about 3 hours ago. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/3bf0639873c3385a3dd539873922dce448185ca8

Comment: And of course the first RC for YII2 just came out today. http://www.yiiframework.com/news/80/yii-2-0-rc-is-released/. Do you plan to incorporate it in to craft this year or do you think it won't be ready for a while yet?

Comment: @KeithMancuso https://twitter.com/d3solutions_sf/status/516248115116900352